# Character encoding issue with accent

Tags: php, encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have a weird issue with a php page.
Here is the php

```
<?
    $fp = fopen('encoding.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($fp, "côté");
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

When i try to view the txt file using a browser http://local.host/encoding.txt the result is :

```
cÃ´tÃ©
```

When i edit the source the result is :

```
cÃ´tÃ©
```

But when i download the file trough filezilla and edit it with textedit the result is :

```
côté
```

What did i missed ?

I already tried (did not change anything):

```
$fp = fopen('encoding.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, utf8_encode("côté"));
fclose($fp);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you need to set the proper encoding (french) in your browser for this particular page to see it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file is saved as UTF-8 and the Browser use UTF-8 Encoding.
Maybe that's enough.